# Camera Shortcut onClick

Tags: android, camera, onclick, android-camera, shortcut

Simple question. Is it possible to allow a button (preferably a FAB) to open a camera app, sort of as a short cut? This shortcut can either lead to the default camera, or lead to any downloaded camera apps.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the standard Camera intent shown on the Android developer website, but I want this to act as a shortcut to the app. Not as a direct link to the camera itself.

Comment: More details: Similar to how when you click share in any app, it'll pull up a list of apps to use. I want this to happen with the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can create an **implicit** intent with action `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

eg:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
String imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

To handle the result:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                Bitmap resultAsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }
```

PS: Don't forget to add your permissions in manifest file.